# python subprocess.popen redirect to create a file

Tags: python, postgresql

I've been searching for how to do this without any success. I've inherited a python script for performing an hourly backup on our database. The original script is too slow, so I'm trying a faster utility. My new command would look like this if typed into a shell:

```
pg_basebackup -h 127.0.0.1 -F t -X f -c fast -z -D - --username=postgres > db.backup.tgz
```

The problem is that the original script uses `call(cmd)` and it fails if the above is the cmd string. I've been looking for how to modify this to use popen but cannot find any examples where a file create redirect is used as in
`>`. The pg_basebackup as shown will output to stdout. The only way I've succeeded so far is to change `-D -` to `-D some.file.tgz` and then move the file to the archive, but I'd rather do this in one step.

### Any ideas?

Jay

Answer (score 0):

May be like this ?

```
with open("db.backup.tgz","a") as stdout:
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_without_redirector, stdout=stdout, stderr=stdout, shell=True)
        p.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... The pg_basebackup executable must be able to attach to that file. If I open the file in the manner you suggest, I don't know the correct syntax in python to be able to do that. If I try putting either " > " or " >> " in the string to call with cmd(), python pukes on it. That's my real problem that I'm not finding any guidance on.